# Poetry NoCompatiblePythonVersionFound

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-poetry

I understand that the Poetry project is working with a different version of Python than I have installed.

How might I rectify this issue though? Preferably, Poetry and the project can use the latest Python version.

#### Terminal

```
cd /mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/project
poetry run python -m project

python3 --version
```

#### Output

```
The currently activated Python version 3.8.10 is not supported by the project (3.8.8).
Trying to find and use a compatible version.

  NoCompatiblePythonVersionFound

  Poetry was unable to find a compatible version. If you have one, you can explicitly use it via the "env use" command.

  at ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/utils/env.py:768 in create_venv
       764│                     python_minor = ".".join(python_patch.split(".")[:2])
       765│                     break
       766│
       767│             if not executable:
    →  768│                 raise NoCompatiblePythonVersionFound(
       769│                     self._poetry.package.python_versions
       770│                 )
       771│
       772│         if root_venv:


Python 3.8.10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to set up a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).

To do this in [Conda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conda_(package_manager)):

```
conda create -n env_name python=3.8.8
```